# Return either result from two queries

Tags: mysql

I have a login query that I wanna run against two conditions. Basically, in query number 1 I check if the member is connected to any contract in my system and in query 2 I check if the member owns any unit in my system.

I want to set up a query that runs both, and if either returns a result (m.*) then that result should be returned.

What I have not are the two queries below that I wanna make one out of:

```
select m.* FROM member m
inner join unit_contract_member ucm on ucm.member_id = m.id
inner join unit_contract uc on uc.id = ucm.contract_id
inner join unit u on u.id = uc.unit_id
where m.usr = 'test@gmail.com'
and m.pwd = 'test'
and u.community_id = 1
and m.active = true
and uc.active = true;

select m.* from member m
inner join unit_owner uo on uo.member_id = m.id
inner join unit u on u.id = uo.unit_id
where m.usr = 'test@gmail.com'
and m.pwd = 'test'
and u.community_id = 1
and m.active = true;
```

Can anyone help out with this? Would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Both table have same fields mean your using union all concept it will show all records .

Comment: Sorry, not too familiar with UNION ALL, could you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

```
IF EXISTS(select m.* FROM member m
       inner join unit_contract_member ucm on ucm.member_id = m.id
       inner join unit_contract uc on uc.id = ucm.contract_id
       inner join unit u on u.id = uc.unit_id
       where m.usr = 'test@gmail.com'
       and m.pwd = 'test'
       and u.community_id = 1
       and m.active = true
       and uc.active = true)
       SELECT m.* FROM member m
       inner join unit_contract_member ucm on ucm.member_id = m.id
       inner join unit_contract uc on uc.id = ucm.contract_id
       inner join unit u on u.id = uc.unit_id
       where m.usr = 'test@gmail.com'
       and m.pwd = 'test'
       and u.community_id = 1
       and m.active = true
       and uc.active = true
ELSE
       select m.* from member m
       inner join unit_owner uo on uo.member_id = m.id
       inner join unit u on u.id = uo.unit_id
       where m.usr = 'test@gmail.com'
       and m.pwd = 'test'
       and u.community_id = 1
       and m.active = true;
```